# Did this command do anything to my Operating System?

Tags: macos, command-line, path

[image]

I was just trying to type in this command: `echo "export PATH=$PATH:~/Desktop/nand2tetris/tools" >> ~/.zshrc ; source ~/.zshrc`

But I got to `echo "export PATH=$PATH:~/Des` before I pressed TAB to autocomplete and then this plethora a of directories suddenly popped up as you can see. I accidentally pressed ENTER a couple of times (I know I'm very clumsy).

So, is this a big deal? Did it do anything to the system?

From what I understand, it is just listing all the directories where the executables are, but my knowledge is very limited on the `echo "export PATH=$PATH` command.

macOS Sonoma 14.4

M2 MBA 2023

Thank you

Comment: `echo` just outputs text to `stdout` unless redirected. You did nothing adverse to your system.    What are you trying yo do?

Comment: That's good to hear. I was just trying to execute this command: `echo "export PATH=$PATH:~/Desktop/nand2tetris/tools" >> ~/.zshrc ; source ~/.zshrc` but pressed TAB to autocomplete directory  and accidentally pressed ENTER.

Comment: That command would have written that text to `.zshrc`. Go ahead and self answer and I’ll upvote

Comment: Side note: you should use `echo 'export "PATH=$PATH:~/Desktop/nand2tetris/tools"' >> ~/.zshrc` instead at least (note the change in quoting). As given, you will hard-code `PATH` in your `.zshrc` to the value in your current session + the extra you're adding. The corrected version will add the extra value to the whatever inherited `PATH`value the shell gets on startup.

Comment: "I accidentally pressed ENTER a couple of times (I know I'm very clumsy)" then **do not enter commands live in the terminal shell prompt, *ever***. Seriously. The shell takes commands with under the principle that "the user always knows what they are doing", and will happily let you destroy your computer under the assumption that you meant to do exactly that. Type shell commands into a sticky note or plain text document and *paste* them in to the shell once you're sure they're correct.

Comment: May be worth pointing out that in relatively-recent versions of macOS, the operating system is mounted on a separate, read-only volume, and so you _can't_ make any changes to it even if you want to!  (Well, not unless you're an expert and go to _far_ more trouble than just running a few Terminal commands.)  However, it's not hard to delete or corrupt your _own_ files, and possible to destroy third-party apps, settings, config, emails, contacts, and just about anything _other_ than the OS — so it's still worth knowing what you're doing and taking care when using the Terminal…

Answer (score 11):

No damage with what's pasted to your system. It simply said "hello" by echoing some content to the window. Even if you ran the export - you can fix that by ending the shell and opening a new command-line window in the terminal.app of your choice.

Answer (score 6):

This is a good learning opportunity and no one seems to have broken down what your commands were doing, so I'll go:

`echo "export PATH=$PATH:~/Desktop/nand2tetris/tools" >> ~/.zshrc ; source ~/.zshrc`

The above are two separate commands, separated by semicolon (as commands on 'bash like shells' (like Zsh shell) always are). The first one is this:

`echo "export PATH=$PATH:~/Desktop/nand2tetris/tools" >> ~/.zshrc`

First of all, `echo` is kind of like a dummy command - it simply outputs whatever you provide as input (in quotes) to 'standard output'. But what makes it powerful is that you can take that output and redirect it somewhere else - in this particular case, you are redirecting its output to the "~/.zshrc " file using the `>>` (append to file) command.
Meaning if I do `echo "Hi" >> file1.txt`, then `>>` will simply append "Hi" to a file called file1.txt (creating the file first, if it doesn't already exist).

Now let's focus on what input you had provided to `echo` (recall quotes were used only because 'echo' needs them, but the actual command is what's inside the quotes):

`export PATH=$PATH:~/Desktop/nand2tetris/tools`

**The export command helps "update" the $PATH environment variable**. The PATH env var specifies all directories to be searched when you type in *any* command. E.g. if you type `python` - your (zsh) shell will search all the directories in PATH to find if there is any "python" in your system. (The 'echo', 'export' commands would themselves be searched in this way, but they're a little too special so they're built in/reserved. But same idea!)

Now **what is PATH being updated to?** First, note that `export PATH=$PATH` will update PATH to the *already existing* PATH variable - i.e. it won't update anything at all. To see your existing PATH, type `echo $PATH`. It should give you a ":" separated string of directories in your existing path (equal to what you showed in your scshot above).

**But you're actually asking it to **append** "~/Desktop/nand2tetris/tools" to your existing PATH** when you say `export PATH=$PATH:~/Desktop/nand2tetris/tools` (note the ":" here).

**You're getting a "plethora of directories suddenly pop up" because the shell autocompleted what $PATH stands for and is simply expanding that part** (`echo $PATH`) **out.**

So what should happen after you run this first command? It should append the line `export PATH=$PATH:~/Desktop/nand2tetris/tools` in your `.zshrc` file. Make sure that's the case: `cat ~/.zshrc` !

Finally, `source ~/.zshrc` is just refreshing your zshrc file so that every command in it (including export commands) are executed (appending a command is not enough; you also have to execute it for its effect to take place - in this case, adding the new path to the PATH env variable).

Comment: You've explained what the OP _meant_ to type, but looking at the screenshot they've pasted into their question, that's not actually what they typed. They left out the redirect to `~/.zshrc` and the sourcing of `~/.zshrc`. All they've done is echoed some stuff to console.

Comment: Lol, yes in fact OP typed only as far as `echo "export PATH=$PATH` before hitting tab. Did not actually type `echo "export PATH=$PATH:~/Des`, like they claimed (otherwise `~/Des` would have been present at the end of the expanded path)

Answer (score 0):

The echo command only outputs what was on the command line to standard output. That is what you saw with all of the junk repeated again (minus echo and escape characters). The command you ran made no changes to your system at all.

Had you gotten to the `>> ~/.zshrc ; source ~/.zshrc` part it would have appended standard output to that file `.zshrc` and you would *not* have seen the repeated stuff on the terminal (it would be in the file instead).

It is fun to be all leet-haxor about echoing to redirection and pipes and whatnot, but you can also just open `.zshrc` in a completely normal text editor and paste `export PATH=$PATH:~/Desktop/nand2tetris/tools` right on in at the end. This has the added benefit of that you can do sanity check stuff like making sure it is not already there!

Also if you don't want to fuss with modifying your path (and the risks involved with it being user writable) you can do `~/Desktop/nand2tetris/tools/whatever-command-you-would-run`